# test if model exists in callback, if it does update, else create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model called Product.

`p = Product.new(...) and
p.save`

I wanna acomplish the following:

If there is another product with the same id(not pk), then we update the product, else we create a new one.

I think this can be done in a callback before_save maybe!?

I tryied like this

```
before_save :try, on: :create

def try
   p = Product.where(id: self.id).first
   p and p.update_attributes(...) and return false
   *1
end
```

*1, at this point, the attributes are updated, it return false that means the new model is not created, but i think the db is rolled back because the update is not saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`find_or_create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Dynamic+attribute-based+finders) (or `find_or_initialize` to only initialize and not save the instance).

Also: I wouldn't make a method named [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) since it already exists to try a method which returns nil if it doesn't exist (instead of an exception).

For example:

```
Product.find_or_create(self.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do an [`upsert`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upsert).

Allthough this command does not exist in ActiveRecord. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695563/upsert-in-rails-activerecord) is an answer that let's you implement such behaviour.