# Updating if exist or create if not rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, insert-update

So im using an api to get info on weather, its executes everyday, what im trying to do is to get updated if already exist, and create a new one if it doesn't in table.
I do want to update all attributs when udpdating.
i did try

```
model = Model.where(column_name: value).first_or_initialize(locked: false)
```

but i get an error saying :

> unknown attribute locked for Model

> raise UnknownAttributeError.new(self ,k.to_s)

If you need anything, ask and i will comment or edit. Im newb to ruby and rails

Comment: Just no `locked` attribute for your `Model` :)

Comment: @mechnicov could you explain a little bit, i still dont really know what locked: false does. But if i eliminate locked: false from that line its just create news and not updating already existing ones.  And if i put trtue, getts same erros as false

Comment: When you call [`first_or_initialize`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize) you need to pass model attributes as arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upsert in Rails ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695563/upsert-in-rails-activerecord)

Comment: i did see there is that upsert method, but im newb in rais and ruby, and i cant get to understand how to use it, could you give an exemple if you know ?

Comment: Please post your models fields

Comment: Could you maybe post the result of running this on rails console? `Model.attribute_names`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `model.Model` part should be just `Model`, as `Model` is your class.

`locked` is supposed to be a column/attribute of the Model class, although it seems is not the case judging from your error. Therefore, I'm gonna use `other_column_name` as an example.

Explanation of what this is doing:

```
Model.where(column_name: value).first_or_initialize(other_column_name: some_value)
```

`Model.where(column_name: value)`: gets models that satisfy the condition column_name == value

`first_or_initialize`: if a model such that column_name == value was found, that one is returned. Otherwise, it initializes a model with column_name = value.

By passing `other_column_name: some_value`, if the model was not found and needs to be initialized, it sets `other_column_name` to `some_value` but: 1) it does not update it if it was initially found and 2) it does not save the record.

The equivalent of `first_or_initialize` that saves the new record would be `first_or_create` but this would still not update the record if it already existed.

So, you should do something like this:

```
m = Model.where(column_name: value).first_or_initialize
m.other_column_name = some_value
m.save
```

This way, you first get a model where `column_name` is `value` or initialize a new one with this value if it didn't already exist. Then, you set the attribute `other_column_name` to `some_value` and save the model.

A one-liner alternative would be

```
Model.where(column_name: value).first_or_create.update(other_column_name: some_value)
```

However, note that if it needs to be created, this one will perform 2 queries (the insert and the update).

About the error part. It says the attribute locked does not exist on the Model record. Are these classes you created? Are you using some pre-existing project? You could try posting `Model.attribute_names` and maybe your schema.rb

Comment: `locked` is not valid attribute for this model. Please look error message above. Also we don't know rails version, `update_attributes` is deprecated in new versions

Comment: @mechnicov Read the last paragraph. I already mentioned the error part in the answer, but I can't know more unless the OP posts the model's atrributes. What I did is to explain what the code did and how to do what was asked (create or update if the record exists). From there, if they post more details, I can help more. You are right about `update_attributes`

Comment: Code in your answer will raise error, so it's not relevant

Comment: @mechnicov, so explaining what their code does and how to achieve what they ask with the little available infro is irrelevant?? I think it was pretty clear in the answer that locked didn't seem to be a correct attribute but I edited it so it is even more clear. As said, we could help more if we had more info but I believe this answer can make the OP understand the code, this makes it somehow relevant to me.

Comment: Now after editing the message, it has become clearer `d(￣◇￣)b`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly refer to the docs [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by)
A table by the name of weather with the following attributes `location: string temperature:integer wind:string` needing to be updated or initialized based on the location would work like this

```
 @weather_record = Weather.find_or_initialize_by(location: location_value)
 @weather.temperature = -60
 @weather.wind = strong
 @weather.save
```

Next, never, ever use a reserved name for a model so do not have Model as the name of your table

Lastly in your example

```
model.Model.where(column_name: value).first_or_initialize(locked: false)
```

you are saying
`a_record.ClassName.where` which is just wrong, If you are using a class method then start with the class name e.g. `Weather.where` if you are using instance methods then use the instance name e.g. `an_instance_of_weather.some_field`

Answer (score 1):

Try this mate:

```
column_name_value = (Way that you get the info from data)
model = Model.find_or_initialize_by column_name: column_name_value
```

Let me know if worked!